# ARM - Add multiple VM to Recovery Services Vault (copyIndex)

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to use the Recovery Services where I can automatically add a VM to Azure Backup via ARM template. I have successfully done this on a single machine deploy, but I'm trying to import it for when multiple VMs are deployed.

Here is where I had help from:
https://www.francoisdelport.com/2017/03/automating-azure-vm-backups-using-arm-templates/

and

[Azure ARM JSON template - Add VM to Recovery Services Vault in different Resource Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884921/azure-arm-json-template-add-vm-to-recovery-services-vault-in-different-resourc)

Here is a snippet from a single deploy I had working

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "nestedTemplate",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "resourceGroup": "Env1",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "template": {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {},
      "variables": {},
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
          "name": "[concat( parameters('recoveryVault'), '/Azure/', 'iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg') , ';', parameters('vmPrefix'), '/vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg'),';', parameters('vmPrefix'))]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
          "properties": {
            "protectedItemType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "policyId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('recoveryVault'), parameters('recoveryPolicy'))]",
            "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('vmRsg'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmPrefix'))]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use that in a copyIndex form for VM deploy, and here is the code I've been testing with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Password for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "dnsNameForPublicIP": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Globally unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "windowsOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2008-R2-SP1",
        "2012-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2-Datacenter"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version. Allowed values: 2008-R2-SP1, 2012-Datacenter, 2012-R2-Datacenter."
      }
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataDiskCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1
    },
    "recoveryVault": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Backup vault name"
      }
    },
    "recoveryPolicy": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Backcup policy name"
      }
    },
    "vmPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Prefix for VM names, used with vmCount to build the VM names"
      }
    },
    "vmRsg": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource group where VMs reside"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "imageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "OSDiskName": "osdiskforwindowssimple",
    "nicName": "myVMNic",
    "subnetName": "Subnet",
    "vhdStorageType": "Standard_LRS",
    "publicIPAddressName": "myPublicIP",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "vhdStorageContainerName": "vhds",
    "vmName": "MWindowsVM",
    "vmSize": "Standard_A2",
    "virtualNetworkName": "MyVNET",
    "vnetId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex(1))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "PublicIPAddress"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[concat(parameters('dnsNameForPublicIP'), copyIndex(1))]"
        }
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "publicIpCopy",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex(1))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "NetworkInterface"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex(1)))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "[concat('ipconfig', copyIndex(1))]",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex(1)))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicCopy",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nodeCopy",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(1))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex(1)))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(1))]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": "[parameters('dataDiskCount')]",
              "input": {
                "diskSizeGB": 1023,
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "createOption": "Empty"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex(1)))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "nestedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "Env1",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(1)))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "copy": {
                "name": "protectedItemsCopy",
                "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
              },
              "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
              "name": "[concat( parameters('recoveryVault'), '/Azure/', 'iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg') , ';', parameters('vmPrefix'), copyIndex(1), '/vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg'),';', parameters('vmPrefix'), copyIndex(1))]",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
              "properties": {
                "protectedItemType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                "policyId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('recoveryVault'), parameters('recoveryPolicy'))]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId ,parameters('vmRsg'),'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), copyIndex(1)) )]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Sadly it reports an error when trying to deploy, which I can't figure out why because it seems to be correct.

```
Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'nestedTemplate' at line '198' and column '10' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
The deployment validation failed
```

FYI, line 198 is `"name": "nestedTemplate",`

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what its telling you that you are not supposed to use copyIndex() function in that place. Now why exactly this is happening I don't know, but I do know that inline templates are a mess (for instance they use parent template paremeters, not nested template), I'm pretty sure if you convert that template to a real nested template (so a linked template, completely separate file) the above syntax will work.

Also, I'm handling this in a separate manner. I'm using 1 single nested deployment for each VM I have, so I'm using copy on the deployment resource, not backup resource.

Comment: are you using `copyIndex` on `"Microsoft.Resources/deployments"` for nested or linked templates? I cannot find an example (nor compile) a `"copy"` for linked templates, only nested (and sadly I need linked for the overall template I'm creating).

Comment: well, depends on what you call what. i'm calling a nested template the template that gets executed with a link (so not inline). and its perfectly fine with copy. also, you last sentence makes no sense. you cant make it work the way you want it to work, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon @4c74356b41 answer I was missing the all important `"index":{ "value": "[copyIndex()]"` within `"Microsoft.Resources/deployments"` on the parent template.

For those wanting to know more, have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple

Ensure you have the `('index')` parameter next to those items which need to be duplicated, such as `"[concat(parameters('WHATEVER'), parameters('index'))]"`

I also ended up having a nested source within my linked template for the overall design I was looking for.

So my parent template had a linked (child) template (to another file) with:

```
name": "[concat('nestings', copyIndex(1))]",
"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments", ...
```

My child template had all the usual buildings of a VM with the parameters `('index')` to ensure the items which are duplicated are named correctly.

And finally at the bottom of the child template I had a nested template source so I could back the VM up to another resource group (had to be nested, otherwise you can't do multiple resource groups), which looked like this:

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "[concat('nestedTemplate', parameters('index'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "Env1",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(variables('vmName'), parameters('index')))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
              "name": "[concat( parameters('recoveryVault'), '/Azure/', 'iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg') , ';', concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), parameters('index')), '/vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;', parameters('vmRsg'),';', concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), parameters('index')))]",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
              "properties": {
                "protectedItemType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                "policyId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('recoveryVault'), parameters('recoveryPolicy'))]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, parameters('vmRsg'), 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', concat(parameters('vmPrefix'), parameters('index')))]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```