# Unable to add vm to RecoveryServiceVault during loop

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build a set of vms through a loop, I'd like to add these vm's recovery services vault and the backup policy, this works on a single vm however I'm getting the following error when I add `copyIndex(1)` to friendlyName.

The recovery services section is below:

```
 {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),copyIndex(1),'recoveryServicesVault')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('recoveryServicesVaultResourceGroup')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMNames'),copyIndex(1))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('recoveryServicesVaultName'), '/', 'Azure', '/', variables('rsvV2vm'), resourceGroup().name, ';', parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1))]",
              "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
              "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
              "properties": {
                "friendlyName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1), 'BackupIntent')]",
                "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
                "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('recoveryServicesVaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('recoveryServicesVaultName'), parameters('recoveryServicesVaultBackupPolicyName'))]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('VMNames'))]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

The full code is at:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/7LSB7Lkb

Can this be done through a loop?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry bud, error `            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"UserErrorInvalidRequestParameter\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Parameter IntentName in request is invalid\\r\\nPlease provide correct value for 
parameter IntentName\",\r\n    \"target\": null,\r\n    \"details\": null,\r\n    \"innerError\": null\r\n  }\r\n}"
          }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure, but it looks like your `name` for the backup is not valid:

```
"[concat(variables('vaultName'), '/', variables('backupFabric'), '/', variables('protectionContainer'), '/', variables('protectedItem'))]",
```

this example contains 4 parts, yours only 3.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-recovery-services-create-vm-and-configure-backup/azuredeploy.json#L210
this might also help: [Azure ARM JSON template - Add VM to Recovery Services Vault in different Resource Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884921/azure-arm-json-template-add-vm-to-recovery-services-vault-in-different-resourc)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I’ll give it a whirl and see how it goes.. thanks for your help today 

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: nah from what I’ve read it looks like it needs to be a nested template, so created a nested template. The answer you provided helped and the links pointed me in the right direction.