# JsonToken EndObject error with nested Template

Tags: json, azure

I'm trying to create a nested template which would do encryption using recovery vault in Azure.

When I attempt to run the main template I get the following error, I'm not sure how to drill down into resources[3].resources.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : JsonToken EndObject is not valid for 

closing JsonType Array. Path 'resources[3].resources', line 533, position 6.
At line:17 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "ThreeDeployment" -ResourceG ...
```

The full template is at
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/6ySqyhtH

I've checked the template and it seems to be ok, although I could be wrong :(

I've been fololwing a previous question\answer on
[Azure ARM JSON template - Add VM to Recovery Services Vault in different Resource Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884921/azure-arm-json-template-add-vm-to-recovery-services-vault-in-different-resourc)

Thanks in advance and I'm sure I should be somewhere better on new years eve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means that you didnt close the resources array of the 4th resource in the template.

```
resources[3].resources
^         ^  ^ resources property of the fourth resource.
^         ^ resource index starting at 0
^ resource property of the template
```

proper sample: https://paste.ee/p/DlPOD

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks again mate :)