# Set up Azure Backup on VM - Recovery Service Vault in a different resource group in same subscription - BICEP

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

Am stumped by this. I am trying to add a vm to a recovery service account but am not succeeding at all. I am aware of this ticket [Azure ARM JSON template - Add VM to Recovery Services Vault in different Resource Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884921/azure-arm-json-template-add-vm-to-recovery-services-vault-in-different-resourc) which references the issue in JSON. I have also succeeded by directly referring to the VNET being in a different resource group.

I was hoping someone could share the BICEP code for setting this backup job up in a different resource group.

```
    @description('Username for the Virtual Machine.')
param adminUsername string

@description('Password for the Virtual Machine.')
@minLength(12)
@secure()
param adminPassword string
param rgName string = 'resroucegroup1'

@description('The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version.')
@allowed([
  '2016-datacenter-gensecond'
  '2016-datacenter-server-core-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-server-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-with-containers-g2'
  '2016-datacenter-zhcn-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-core-with-containers-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-gensecond'
  '2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-with-containers-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-with-containers-smalldisk-g2'
  '2019-datacenter-zhcn-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core-smalldisk'
  '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-smalldisk'
  '2022-datacenter-core-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-core-smalldisk-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-g2'
  '2022-datacenter-smalldisk-g2'
])
param OSVersion string = '2022-datacenter-azure-edition'

@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v5'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = 'australiaeast'
//resourceGroup().location

@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string = 'simple-vm'

@description('Security Type of the Virtual Machine.')
@allowed([
  'Standard'
  'TrustedLaunch'
])
param securityType string = 'TrustedLaunch'

var storageAccountName = 'bootdiagsabcdeg'
var nicName = 'myVMNic2'
var addressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'
var subnetName = 'Subnet'

var subnetID = '/subscriptions/xyzsubscription/resourceGroups/resroucegroup1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/MyVNET/subnets/Subnet'

var subnetPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
var virtualNetworkName = 'MyVNET'
var networkSecurityGroupName = 'default-NSG2'
var securityProfileJson = {
  uefiSettings: {
    secureBootEnabled: true
    vTpmEnabled: true
  }
  securityType: securityType
}
var extensionName = 'GuestAttestation'
var extensionPublisher = 'Microsoft.Azure.Security.WindowsAttestation'
var extensionVersion = '1.0'
var maaTenantName = 'GuestAttestation'
var maaEndpoint = substring('emptyString', 0, 0)

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}


resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  scope: resourceGroup(rgName)
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2022-07-01' existing = {
  name: subnetName
  parent: virtualNetwork
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2022-05-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          // publicIPAddress: {
          //   id: publicIp.id
          // }
          subnet: {
            id: subnetID
            //subnet.id
            //resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', virtualNetworkName, subnetName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [

    // virtualNetwork
  ]
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-03-01' = {
  name: vmName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vmSize
    }
    osProfile: {
      computerName: vmName
      adminUsername: adminUsername
      adminPassword: adminPassword
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: OSVersion
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: 'StandardSSD_LRS'
        }
      }
      dataDisks: [
        {
          diskSizeGB: 128
          lun: 0
          createOption: 'Empty'
        }
      ]
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic.id
        }
      ]
    }
    diagnosticsProfile: {
      bootDiagnostics: {
        enabled: true
        storageUri: storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob
      }
    }
    securityProfile: ((securityType == 'TrustedLaunch') ? securityProfileJson : json('null'))
  }
}

resource vmExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2022-03-01' = if ((securityType == 'TrustedLaunch') && ((securityProfileJson.uefiSettings.secureBootEnabled == true) && (securityProfileJson.uefiSettings.vTpmEnabled == true))) {
  parent: vm
  name: extensionName
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: extensionPublisher
    type: extensionName
    typeHandlerVersion: extensionVersion
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      AttestationConfig: {
        MaaSettings: {
          maaEndpoint: maaEndpoint
          maaTenantName: maaTenantName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI) works for you! @treeof

Comment: I tried but they don’t have information on connecting to a different resource groups and it’s recovery service vault. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.recoveryservices/recovery-services-vm-workload-backup/main.bicep

Comment: So, you are trying to create a recovery service in different resource group but not the remaining ones, right? Correct me if my understanding is wrong. @treeof

Comment: I am trying to connect to an existing recovery service built in another resource group in the same subscription.

Comment: I see the following code in the GitHub example: resource protectionContainer 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers@2021-03-01' = {
  name: '${vaultName}/${backupFabric}/${containerType};compute;${vmResourceGroup};${vmName}'
  properties: {
    containerType: containerType
    backupManagementType: backupManagementType
    workloadType: workloadType
    friendlyName: vmName
    sourceResourceId: resourceId(vmResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', vmName)
  }
  dependsOn: [
    recoveryServicesVault
    backupPolicy
  ]
}

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.recoveryservices/recovery-services-vm-workload-backup/main.bicep)?

Comment: How do I refer to this existing recovery service instead of building a new one.

Comment: Yes that’s the one

Comment: Trying in my environment with the same github.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing with the GitHub code?

Comment: The GitHub code is fine if I wanted to backup a vm in the same resource group. But what if my recovery site is in a different resource group? This is where I can’t figure out. I tried existing prompt but there is no way to set up a scope in this existing resource

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out thanks to an answer in the github repo for bicep.

- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/10263
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-to-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli#scope-to-different-resource-group

In my main bicep file:

```
    //Backup Policy variables
var vaultName = 'Enter your vault name'
var vaultResourceGroup = 'Enter your vault resource group which is different'
var vaultSubscription = 'Enter your subscription id here'
var backupFabric = 'Azure'
var backupPolicyName = 'Enter the recovery service vault - backup policy that is already setup by you'
var protectionContainer = 'iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;${resourceGroup().name};${vmName}'
var protectedItem = 'vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;${resourceGroup().name};${vmName}'

------- After VM is spun up ------------------------

module vaultModule 'main_vault.bicep' = {
name: 'vaultModule'
scope: resourceGroup(vaultSubscription, vaultResourceGroup)
params:{
vaultName: vaultName
backupFabric: backupFabric
backupPolicyName: backupPolicyName
protectionContainer: protectionContainer
protectedItem: protectedItem
vm: vm.id
}
}
```

and in the 'main_vault.bicep' file:

```
param vaultName string
param backupFabric string
param backupPolicyName string
param protectionContainer string
param protectedItem string
param vm string

resource recoveryServicesVault 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults@2023-01-01' existing ={

name: vaultName

}

resource vaultName_backupFabric_protectionContainer_protectedItem 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems@2023-01-01' = {

name: '${vaultName}/${backupFabric}/${protectionContainer}/${protectedItem}'

properties :{

protectedItemType: 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
policyId: '${recoveryServicesVault.id}/backupPolicies/${backupPolicyName}'
sourceResourceId: vm

}

}
```

The key are the variables:

```
  var vaultName = 'Enter your vault name'
  var vaultResourceGroup = 'Enter your vault resource group which is different'
  var vaultSubscription = 'Enter your subscription id here'
```

This is passed through to the scope statement which refocuses the vault and the bicep module in the other resource group.